# How to show the row number in ag-grid with aurelia?

Tags: aurelia, ag-grid

This ist the code of my grid in aurelia:

```
<ag-grid-aurelia #agGrid class="ag-theme-balham" style="width: 35%; height: 350px;" pagination="true" grid-options.bind="gridOptions2">
  <ag-grid-column header-name="ID" width.bind="100"> </ag-grid-column>
  <ag-grid-column header-name="Entity" valueGetter field="entity" width.bind="300"></ag-grid-column>
  <ag-grid-column header-name="Count" field="count" width.bind="150"></ag-grid-column>
</ag-grid-aurelia>
```

How can I display the row number in the "ID" column?

Answer (score 0):

node.rowIndex might help.

Something like this maybe?

```
var columnDefs = [
  { headerName: 'RowNumber', valueGetter: 'node.rowIndex'},
...
```